# Creating a random story generator using pointers and arrays to deal with strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings, srand

I am trying to figure out how I should structure my next lab for programming class. Here's what I have so far. Questions go line by line:

```
int main()
{       
    char name, color, person; //color, pet and car are the only arrays. The rest will be read in
    int age;

    const char* pet[5]={"dog", "cat", "bird", "snake", "monkey"}; //not sure how to set up these pointers...
    const char* car[5]={"porsche 911", "honda prelude", "toyota prius", "shelby mustang"};

    printf("What is your name?   \n");
    scanf("%c", &name);
    printf("How old are you?  \n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("What is your favorite color?  \n");
    scanf("%c", &color);
    printf("What is the name of your best friend?  \n");
    scanf("%c", &person);


    printf("%c is an awesome person.\n", name);
    printf(" They are currently %d years old and drive a %c %s.\n", age, color, car[5]); // trying to reference array in text
    printf(" %c 's best friend, %c, picks them up in a %s and drives them over to see their pet %s", name, person, car[5], pet[5]); // trying to reference array in text

    pet[5]=srand(time(NULL));// Where should this go? do I need one to reference each array?
    car[5]=srand(time(NULL));

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Updated 4:17 10/22. The only compiling error I am receiving now is relating the arrays to the srand function

Comment: You probably need quotes around the strings like "dog", "cat" and such. Have you tried compiling this? You are also trying to put 5 values in an array of size 4 for the pets.

Comment: `char[4]=srand(time(null));` ... what?

Comment: You cannot input more than one character as a `name`, and the other strings; and `%c` is not useful to print a string. `car[5]` is out of range (and so is `pet[5]`). These, and your odd use of `srand`, suggests you probably need to read a standard manual or book before retrying. (You might even find an alternative for that cursed line `system("pause");` found in so many low quality questions.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues.

- `name`, `color` and `person` should be **arrays** of `char` and not `char`
- indexes for `car[5]` and `pet[5]` are out of range
- `pet[5]=srand(time(NULL));` I have no clue what you want to achieve with this. It doesn't make any sens. You should update your question and elaborate.

Corrected code so far:

```
int main()
{       
    char name[50], color[50], person[50]; //color, pet and car are the only arrays. The rest will be read in
    int age;

    const char* pet[5]={"dog", "cat", "bird", "snake", "monkey"}; //not sure how to set up these pointers...
    const char* car[5]={"porsche 911", "honda prelude", "toyota prius", "shelby mustang"};

    printf("What is your name?   \n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("How old are you?  \n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("What is your favorite color?  \n");
    scanf("%s", color);
    printf("What is the name of your best friend?  \n");
    scanf("%s", person);

    printf("%s is an awesome person.\n", name);
    printf(" They are currently %d years old and drive a %s %s.\n", age, color, car[4]); // trying to reference array in text
    printf(" %s 's best friend, %s, picks them up in a %s and drives them over to see their pet %s", name, person, car[3], pet[4]); // trying to reference array in text

    //no clue what this should be
    //pet[5]=srand(time(NULL));// Where should this go? do I need one to reference each array?
    //car[5]=srand(time(NULL));

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```